# How to run parallel jdk version

Tags: java

I installed a new jdk 1.6 parallel to that existing 1.5, however I got this error when I run the java  binary.

./java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

I already set my PATH variable to include the new jdk bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your JAVA_HOME variable to the base directory instead.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.5r8
/path/to/jdk1.5r8/bin/java -version
```

Java respects JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTS for almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

This what I setup in the bash profile in our servers.

```
export JAVA_HOME_8=$HOME/3rd/jdk1.8.0
export JAVA_HOME_6=$HOME/3rd/jdk1.6.0_38

alias j6='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_6;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
alias j8='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_8;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH'
```

When we need java6 we type j6 in the command prompt to load the java6 environment or j8 to load the java8 environment

Answer (score 0):

make sure the jdk version you want to use in PATH and JAVA_HOME are same. you can keep switching between the versions by updating the two fields.